# Upgrade to Maverick broke the display resolution - Dell Studio

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, display, graphics

My system used to display the Full HD resolution - the native, very well on the Karmic.

I upgraded my system to Maverick and the maximum 16:9 resolution X server supports is 1280x720.

As far as I can remember, I didn't have to do any changes for the display back when I originally installed 10.04.

From the `lspci`, the graphics card I have is the one follows:

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]

How can I get back the high native resolution?

Comment: Have you checked System > Administration > Additional Drivers?

Comment: Marco, Thanks, but the additional driver is installed, activated and currently in use. :(

Comment: How did you determine that's the maximum supported resolution?  Just that it's the highest thing listed in the graphical display tool? Or did https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding%20undetected%20resolutions fail for you?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, not sure if I should delete the question. But I am sure some people may face same issue, so I will just answer it anyway.

Disable the additional driver, enable it and then restart, boom, everything back to normal!

Comment: Don't delete it. It helped me :)

Comment: Had a similiar issue and came to the same conclusion. Thanks for posting it here so that I can see it confirmed here as well!

Answer (score 1):

Maye to extend Lakshman's post (could someone merge it into his response please): 
To have resolution properly detected I needed:

- delete xorg.conf (it gets recreated then)
- reboot
- System -> Administration -> Additional drivers; and enable there FGLRX Driver
- reboot

Answer (score 1):

Also try `xserver-xorg-video-ati` driver instead of fglrx. Fglrx caused problems with display resolution for me when I connected external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have another computer, but graphic card vendor same (ATI). Try to install original driver by default(http://www.amd.com/uk/Pages/AMDHomePage.aspx) or try from menu System->Preferences->Monitor change monitor resolution.