# Problem with fglrx when updating from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, ati, dell, updates

Well I had some problems with update so I'll post solution.

I use Dell Studio 1555.

My symptoms were that after reboot screen flickered and then I got console login prompt. 
Basically after the upgrade xorg won't start.

I belive it was because updater installed stale fglrx package from `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.(So please before you upgrade do `sudo apt-get clean`)

Comment: The format here is Q&A and this is just an A! I know I'm being a bit anal but could you split your solution into its own answer (using the button near the bottom) and refactor your question into a question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer:

### Step 1:

Delete `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

```
 sudo apt-get clean
```

### Step 2:

Purge fglrx

```
sudo aptitude purge fglrx
```

If you get error that looks like:

```
dpkg-divert: mismatch on package
 when removing `diversion of /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2 to /usr/lib/fglrx  /libGL.so.1.2.xlibmesa by fglrx' 
 found `diversion of /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2 to /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2.xlibmesa by xorg-driver-fglrx'
 dpkg: error processing fglrx (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
 Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx
```

you need to delete fivert linsks:

```
 sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2
 sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove /usr/lib32/libGL.so.1.2
```

and retry purging:

```
sudo aptitude purge fglrx
```

### Step 3:

Reinstall fglrx

```
sudo aptitude install fglrx
```

### Step 4:

Rebuild xorg conf
     sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

After that I got bad resolution. Answer is  [in the following post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5873/upgrade-to-maverick-broke-the-display-resolution-dell-studio).

Answer (score 1):

There is a much more elegant way to achieve step 1

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will automatically remove the downloaded deb archives.